# Reactjs: The Event in Nested component isn't triggered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
interface Props{
   content: ReactNode
   showWithTooltip: boolean
}
export const Item =  ({content, showWithTooltip }: Props) => {
   const Content = () => {
      <Container>{content}</Container>
   }

   return showWithTooltip ? <Tooltip><Content /></Tooltip>: <Content/>
}
```

This is a sample code in real situation the Item structure is more complicated. But the problem I had is when I pass a Button to Item

```
<Item content={<Button onClick={()=>{console.log("show something")}} />} />
```

The event is not triggered. Could someone tell me what is the problem ?

Comment: when you click on your button, do you have error on your console.log?

Comment: I don't think you are returning a component from the Content function call. You should explicitly write return, if you're not using a one line function.

Comment: yeah, that doesn't show error and doesn't trigger onClick function :(

Comment: Yes correct @HaneenMahdin if I use explicitly return, the button will be triggered. But there is legacy code with a lot of logic than I can't modify it. And I would like to understand what is happened too?

Comment: When we return the Container from the Content function call, the component is rendered otherwise the Container function, under the hood is only called but never returned, so instead of rendering the Container, React will render null, which in turns renders nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.But I saw the component is rendered correctly. The only thing wrong is the event from button is not triggered when I click on the button. Sorry if I didn't get your idea correctly